# Embedded images are not working in CKEditor 5

Tags: media, wysiwyg, 10

While migrating CKEditor 4 to 5, images added through entity embed ( E ) option in CKEditor 4 is not appearing after switching to CKEditor 5. Any idea how to make it work in CKEditor 5?

[image: in CKEditor 4]

in CKEditor 4
[image: In CKEditor 5]

in CKEditor 5

The image added in CKEditor 4 is disappearing after swithing to CKEditor 5 as in ckeditor 5 entity embed is not there and using  drupal media.

Comment: If you aren't using the Entity Embed module anymore, how did you migrate the data?

Comment: We are using Entity_embed module through out the site till now in CKEditor 4. But now as CKEditor 4 is nearing EOL we are migrating to CKEditor 5 and This module is not supported in CKEditor 5. We need that data even after migrating to CKEdtitor 5

Comment: Entity Embed module is now compatible with CKE5

Answer (score 1):

Entity Embed does not yet support CKEditor5.  [Work is ongoing here, and you can help move the process forward by testing the latest patch.](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_embed/issues/3272732)

Otherwise, you can wait for a release of the Entity Embed plugin that supports CKEditor 5.

Alternately, you could write your own code to replicate what the Entity Embed module does... but why do that when you can help the community and save time yourself by working on the Entity Embed module directly?

Answer (score 0):

Entity embed does not have an official release for D10 yet, it is still in development. There is an [issue you can follow](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_embed/issues/3272732#comment-15037680) for patches and updates.

Comment: We are using Entity_embed module through out the site till now in CKEditor 4. But now as CKEditor 4 is nearing EOL we are migrating to CKEditor 5 and This module is not supported in CKEditor 5.

So I am not able to migrate the images from ckeditor 4 to 5.

Comment: @pvh Yeah it's still in dev, I updated my answer with the issue link to follow.